# Java filesystem crawler - weird results in filecount and ridiculous rate of empty files

Tags: java, windows, filesystems

I'm currently playing with some homework for "probability and statistics" class, something about size of disk segments and efficiency.

I wrote simple file crawler for collecting data

```
public static void addTree(File file, Collection<File> all) {
    File[] children = file.listFiles();
    if (children != null) {
        for (File child : children) {
            addTree(child, all);
        }
    }else{
        all.add(file);
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Collection<File> all = new ArrayList<File>();
    //build file list
    System.out.println("COLLECTING");
    addTree(new File("."), all);
    //result file
    try {
        //result file stream
        FileWriter fstream = null;
        fstream = new FileWriter("result.txt");
        //result file writer
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);

        System.out.println("SAVING STARTED");

        //loop - find size and extension (lowercase)
        Iterator itr = all.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()){
            //get file
            File tested = (File) itr.next();
            //get ext
            String[] splitted = tested.getName().split("\\.");
            String ext = splitted[splitted.length-1];
            //get size
            long size = tested.length();
            //put into file
            //if(size!=0){
                out.write(size+" "+ext);
                out.newLine();
            //}
        }
        //close file / save
        out.close();
    }catch(IOException ex){}
}
```

And I have 2 questions:
1) after scanning my D:/, it showed up crawler found about 480k files, but system claims there is about 507k files. OK, I though probably hidden files or something like that.
BUT after scanning C:/ the score is a bit opposite way - crawler found 229k and windows claims 227k. This is little bit hard for me to understand, how could such thnig even happen.

2) As you can see

```
//if(size!=0){
    out.write(size+" "+ext);
    out.newLine();
//}
```

crawler takes all files (even zero size ones), and it showed up, there is ONLY about 104k nonzero files out od 507k on my D:/ (not OS partition - only application files - no system files related), what seems to me a ridiculous nonsense to have 80% files with absolutely no content. I get it, there is sometimes need to create file for later use, but this looks like someone misinterpreted filename as OS global variable or what.

Can please somebody clarify this issue?

Comment: Just an observation, but directories *may* show up as zero size files. From the javadoc on file.length() `The length, in bytes, of the file denoted by this abstract pathname, or 0L if the file does not exist. Some operating systems may return 0L for pathnames denoting system-dependent entities such as devices or pipes. `

Comment: You could try scanning a small folder and counting the files manually to locate the error. Note that your function `addTree` adds an item to the list if its children is **null**, which may occur for empty folders. Consider using [File.isDirectory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isDirectory()).

Comment: Also, do you have privileges to access that filesystem?